# Translations of the word “memory”

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Can someone explain how to properly translate the term "memory" for different contexts? I.e. "A memory of walking in the park" vs. "I have an excellent memory."

Are *souvenir* and *mémoire* the proper words to be used here? If not, what do they mean exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, *memory* translates to different terms in french, depending on the meaning.

As you presumed :

> A memory of walking in the park (*memory* = *souvenir*)

but

> I have an excellent memory. (*memory* = *mémoire*)

I can't think of any other meanings...

Answer (score 8):

You have the right word for each context. A single memory (i.e. an event) is a "souvenir", but memory in general is "mémoire". Other expressions that have more quirky translations include:

- "in memory of" → "à la mémoire de"/"en souvenir de"
- "have pleasant memories of" → "garder un bon souvenir de"

In computing, "memory" is also "mémoire": "Mémoire vive" "mémoire morte" ("RAM"/"ROM").

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are the good words here.

*Souvenir* is for something you remember, a remembrance... It also design an object who recall a moment of your life to you (like an object you got on a trip).

**"J'ai souvenir d'un long voyage..."** -> I remember a long trip...

**"Je me souviens de ce jour..."** -> I remember this day...

**"J'ai acheté ce souvenir..."** -> I bought this token...

---

*Mémoire* has approximately the same definition than memory and can be sometime used in place of *Souvenir* :

**"J'ai mémoire d'un long voyage..."** -> I remember a long trip...

Comment: "*"J'ai acheté ce souvenir..." -> I bought this token...*". Actually, that would be "*I bought this souvenir.*". Frenglish works both ways.

Comment: Anyone I hear saying "J'ai mémoire d'un long voyage" will be force-fed some medication.

Comment: @Joubarc Pour être honnête, il y a d'autres emplois de *mémoire* sans article, comme dans *si j'ai bonne mémoire de [quelque chose], ...*